# Converting decimal values to non decimal in computed column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to convert decimal values into non decimal number for a computed column in Oracle SQL.

Please see the below code. But I am not able to get the desired output.
Query:

```
Select cast(cost_account)*100/cast(amnt_fin) as "computed_LTV" 
From Loan_app.
```

Here I Want a new column name as `computed_LTV` with the required calculation with no decimal in the output.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of "desired result".

Answer (score 0):

It is `ROUND` you're looking for, I presume.

```
SELECT ROUND (cost_account * 100 / amnt_fin) AS "computed_LTV" FROM Loan_app
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "non-decimal number" you mean "integer", just use `trunc()`:

```
Select trunc(cost_account * 100 / amnt_fin) as computed_LTV
From Loan_app;
```